How would I make updateCirclePosition() update every Screen Refresh?
I'm trying to make a requestAnimationFrame(updateCirclePosition) work but it doesn't seem to.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var object = document.getElementById("circle");

    function updateCirclePosition() {
        var mouseX = event.clientX;
        var mouseY = event.clientY;

        var height = object.offsetHeight;
        var width = object.offsetWidth;

        var rect = object.getBoundingClientRect();
        var elemX = rect.left + window.scrollX;
        var elemY = rect.top + window.scrollY;

        var distanceX = mouseX - elemX;
        var distanceY = mouseY - elemY;

        var targetX = object.offsetLeft + object.offsetWidth / 2;
        var targetY = object.offsetTop + object.offsetHeight / 2;

        var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

        function rotateObject(degrees) {
            object.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'rad)';
        }

        var angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - targetY, mouseX - targetX);

        rotateObject(angle);

        var targX = (mouseX - targetX) / 10;
        var targY = (mouseY - targetY) / 10;

        var targetPosition = [targetX + targX, targetY + targY];

        object.style.left = "calc(" + targetPosition[0] + "px - " + width / 2 + "px)";
        object.style.top = "calc(" + targetPosition[1] + "px - " + height / 2 + "px)";

        requestAnimationFrame(updateCirclePosition);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(updateCirclePosition);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
    });
});

I've tried to make it work with updating as well as Mouse Update, but it never updates automatically, it always requires mouse movement.

PSA: It's 2024 and time to use let and const in preference to var.

Can you expand on "doesn't work" in more technical terms? If you're trying to capture into mouseX, maybe that should be let mouseX = 0 outside of the updateCircleFunction and then make that a closure.

@tadman When I said "doesn't work" i mean it doesn't update every screen refresh.
And what I want is it to update every screen refresh rather than every time the mouse is moved.

What do you mean by "screen refresh"? Is that a window resize event, or on page load/reload? Using requestAnimationFrame will generate a lot of events, but the page itself may be static.

I want something to happen every time the monitor refreshes, for example a 60hz Monitor will send a screen refresh 60 times a second.

You have a variable scope problem. Move the declaration before the closure to ensure both functions are mutating the same thing.

how do i do that bro
